# I have a error( xprop: unable to open display ) on cloud9 when I try $ heroku open

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, terminal, cloud9-ide, heroku-postgres

I'm using the cloud9 and I trying to do in terminal the command:

```
$ heroku open
```

and I have this error:

> romenigld@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/toy_app (master) $ heroku open
>   Opening r-rails-tutorial-toy-app... xprop:  unable to open display ''
>   xprop:  unable to open display ''
>   done

I don't know why, I don't know why occur this, but when I navigate to the heroku page (http://r-rails-tutorial-toy-app.herokuapp.com/ ), works fine!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have the same problem when using `heroku open` in the tutorial. It really sounds like something easy to fix... just some sort of configuration?

Comment: I forget this rschwieb I know this works on my machine with Mac OS X, but on that hour not works in the cloud9. You will need to put manually the url. When the heroku build the server you will take the name generated and put: name.herokuapp.com or with the command `$ heroku rename`and renames the generated url with your preference.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because there's no xwindows running inside the container. You'll have to manually open the URL.

Comment: This is not true because in the before tutorial I do this and open perfect and the platform who has cloud9 is Unix!